# How should one handle a Parent-Child relationship using MVP?

Tags: winforms, mvp

In a conventional [**MDI**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface) [**WinForms**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application, one would go like this:

```
public partial MainMdiForm : Form {
    public MainMdiForm() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void manageCustomersToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var cmf = new CustomerManagementForm();
        cmf.MdiParent = this;
        cmf.Show();
    }
}
```

So that the `CustomerManagementForm` never gets out of bounds.

Using [**Model-View-Presenter**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) along with [**Dependency Injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), the code adds an abstraction layer which actually doesn't allow me to set the [**MdiParent**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent(v=vs.110).aspx) of my view/form.

**MainMdiForm**

```
public partial MainMdiForm : Form, IMainView {
    public MainMdiForm() { InitializeComponent(); }

    public IMainViewUiHandler Handler { get; set; }

    private void manageCustomersToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Handler.ManageCustomers();
    }
}
```

**IMainView**

```
public interface IMainView : IView, IHasUiHandler<IMainViewUiHandler> { }
```

**IHasUiHandler**

```
public interface IHasUiHandler<H> where H : IUiHandler {
    H Handler { get; set; }
}
```

**IUiHandler**

```
public interface IUiHandler { }
```

**IMainViewUiHandler**

```
public interface IMainViewUiHandler : IUiHandler { 
    void ManageCustomers();
}
```

**MainPresenter**

```
public class MainPresenter : Presenter<IMainView>, IMainViewUiHandler {
    public MainPresenter(IMainView view
        , ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory customerManagementPresenterFactory) 
        : base(view) {
        view.Handler = this;
        this.customerManagementPresenterFactory = customerManagementPresenterFactory;
    }

    public void ManageCustomers() {
        var p = customerManagementPresenterFactory.Create();
        p.ShowView();
    }

    private readonly ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory customerManagementPresenterFactory;
}
```

As you can see, there's nowhere to set the [**Form.MdiParent**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent(v=vs.110).aspx) property for the view that the presenter handles. And exposing such property might break the abstraction and tight couple it to WinForms, since no other platform uses such a hierarchy with the different user-interfaces. Although this application is destined to be a simple example of using **MVP** along with **DI**, I wish to make it as clean as possible.

I thought of creating a single interface which would use the **Parent** terminology, and compose my view with it only from within the Windows Forms application, so that other platforms would not inherit from this useless property.

Any idea on how I should go along with this?

Comment: Are you sure that other windowing platforms in majority don't have the concept of a parent window/widget. In any case, you could pass a `Form` reference in the calls to `ManageCustomers` and `Create` and let the factory class determine if it needs a parent link or not and in which property to set it.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau, In short, I can't say that I am sure. To the best of my knowledge, WPF, ASP.NET, and Silverlight don't have this concept. I might be mistaking, I perhaps only never needed such concept on other platforms than WinForms.

Comment: How about you introduce a UI hooking context? The context could be abstract but have one implementer that is aware of the MDI window mechanics and take care of attaching child windows correctly upon call to ShowView. The hooker could be a parameter to the latter, distributed by the MDI parent view (as an hooker interface, for example).

Comment: So I could use an interface with a single property for which my form holds an implementation, and pass it upon a call to `ShowView` like so: `Presenter.ShowView(myParentChildInterface)`. Is this what you're proposing, do I get it correctly?